# What is the origin of "pratfall?"

Tags: etymology, journalism

I came across the word "pratfall" in this journalistic piece:
[eHuffington Post: Donald, you are not in Manhattan anymore](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/donald-trump-manhattan-washington_us_58d43610e4b03692bea3e4ea?)

> But the first ***pratfall*** ― cancelling the vote on the bill after insisting it would go forward ― is not a good sign.

At first I thought it might be a typo for "pitfall," or an example of journalistic license based on the derogatory slang word *prat,* but was surprised that to find that the term, while modern, seems to be established. A Google search yields this:
[image: [2]]
Can anyone shed light on the origin of this word? If it is derived from "prat," then what is *its* origin?

[I have asked another question relating to the same paragraph from which this was taken.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379873/what-effect-is-the-writer-trying-to-create-with-the-use-of-bigly)

Comment: There is  no clear link between prat and the French postérieur or prêter : ***Prat: "buttock," 1560s, criminals' slang, of unknown origin***. Later in U.S. criminal slang, "hip pocket" (1914), and in British slang "contemptible person" (1968). From Etymonline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merriam-Webster (whose definitions you cite in your question) dates the term *pratfall* to 1930. However, a Google Books search finds an example that is a bit earlier. From Lee Wilson Dodd, [*The Great Enlightenment: A Satire in Verse, with Other Selected Verses*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mYxBAAAAIAAJ&q=%22prat+fall%22&dq=%22prat+fall%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifkrrblO7SAhUM32MKHUqPDA0Q6AEIJDAC) (1928) [text not visible in snippet view, but visible [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=oZsjAQAAMAAJ&q=%22do+a+prat+fall+with+the+veriest+clown%22&dq=%22do+a+prat+fall+with+the+veriest+clown%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_zZnOlu7SAhVnzlQKHaVuA80Q6AEIJjAC) from what is supposedly a 1927 source]:

> Once timid in dim corners, like the mouse,
>
> Professors now, like actors, "count the house,"
>
> "Take stage," demand a "spot," inspire a "clack,"
>
> And, to "get laughs," will sit upon a tack,
>
> Or do a "**prat fall**" with the veriest clown
>
> To gain th' attention of our Planet-Town.

Another early spelling of the term is with two *t*'s—but it retains the same meaning. From Roger Whately, ‎Jack O'Donnell & ‎Henry Hanemann, [*The Silver Streak*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QCtDAAAAIAAJ&q=%22prattfall%22&dq=%22prattfall%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd8Mecmu7SAhXqslQKHQM-B64Q6AEIKjAD) (1935):

> **PRATTFALL** — Violent posterior gravitation.

According to Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang*, first edition (1960), *pratt* or *prat* is only slightly older than *pratfall*:

> **prat** [or] **pratt** *n.* The human posterior. **1923:** "Pratt." Hecht & MacArthur, *Front Page*, III. **1946:** "He does not fall on his prat." *Time*, Mar. 11, 63/1. *Very old.* v.t. To move behind someone in order to observe him without being seen or to get into a position to rob him. *Underworld use.*
>
> **prat fall** [or] **pratfall** A fall on the backside or rump; said of a person. *Often used esp. of falls taken by clowns in comedy routines. Wide theater use.* 1939: "A perfect pratfall. ..." Edmund Wilson, New Republic, Apr. 26, 332. ...

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995) essential repeat Wentworth & Flexner's entry for *pratfall*, but they put a number to the age of *prat*, where Wentworth & Flexner had made do with "Very old":

> **prat** or **pratt** ***n*** *by 1567* The buttocks; = ASS ... {origin unknown}

J.S. Farmer & W.E. Henley, *Slang and Its Analogues*, volume 5 (1902) provides a brief excerpt of its early usage in The Merry Wives of Windsor (1596):

> *Mrs. Page.* Come, Mother Prat; ...
>
> *Ford.* I'll **prat** her {Beating him}.

Over the early centuries of its use, however, according to Farmer & Henley, the term *prat* (like the word *buttock*) was more often used in plural form than in singular, as in Richard Brome's [*Jovial Crew*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hPhLAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA306&dq=%22set+me+down+here+on+both+my+prats%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4sv_qoO7SAhUHxFQKHZ_DANsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22set%20me%20down%20here%20on%20both%20my%20prats%22&f=false):

> Fiddle, Patrico, and let me sing. First set me down here on both my **prats**.

Since the 1928 instance of *prat fall* already places the term in the context of clowning behavior, it seems not at all likely that the word originated in vaudeville or earlier theatrical lingo. But I have not been able to find an explanation of why Elizabethans settled on *prat* as argot for buttocks.

Comment: Thank you!  I wonder if the p, r, t consonants shared by "prat" and French "postérieur" are at the root of this.  Or perhaps even the French verb "prêter," to loan — someone in debt to you is a "prat"?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to "pretty", in it's old sense of of a joke or trick? A pratfall is a pretend fall, it's about artifice and appearance (as prettiness can be), a piece of comedic slapstick.

Old English prættig (West Saxon), pretti (Kentish), *prettig (Mercian) "cunning, skillful, artful, wily, astute," from prætt, *prett "a trick, wile, craft," from Proto-Germanic *pratt- (source also of Old Norse prettr "a trick," prettugr "tricky;" Frisian pret, Middle Dutch perte, Dutch pret "trick, joke," Dutch prettig "sportive, funny," Flemish pertig "brisk, clever"), of unknown origin.
https://www.etymonline.com/word/pretty